# blender knife tool artifacts

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface, knife-tool

so im working on a scroll and wanted to a add paper cut to the scroll, i did it by using the knife however when i turn back the subdiviosn modifier (i also have the solidify modifier) back the cut looks weird. is there any way to fix that?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PbXFAukCquUTm6ZZpc9mBqxkkKYH3X30/view?usp=sharing

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your topology is probably bad, maybe show your wireframe or even share this part of your object? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: thanks! i posted the wireframe picture of the object and a google drive link to the object

Comment: please authorize access  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example of a mesh before Catmull-Clark subdivision:

[image]

Subdivision rounds the mesh:

[image] [image]

Removing parts of the geometry interferes with the way it is rounded by the subdivision algorithm:

[image]

And so you could remove that part with a boolean (easier) or a mask modifier (harder since you need to predict how the modifier will move the vertices) after subdivision modifier...

If you don't like the way some paths get wibbly-wobbly like on the 3rd image, you can retopo your mesh to better represent the *flow* of the object, and add holding loops to limit the range of the modifier:

[image] [image]

You can also do a lot with creases (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>):

[image]